# NSImage to cv::Mat and vice versa

Tags: macos, opencv, nsimage, cgimage, cgimageref

while working with OpenCV I need to convert a NSImage to an OpenCV multi-channel 2D matrix (cvMat) and vice versa.

What's the best way to do it?

Greets,
Dom

Comment: This is really helpful, but this is not the way to do it. You need to adapt your material to the Q&A format, so ASK the question first... and then ANSWER it.

Comment: Ah, ok. Edited my first post and answered with my solution :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's my outcome, which works pretty well.

*NSImage+OpenCV.h:*

```
//
//  NSImage+OpenCV.h
//

#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface NSImage (NSImage_OpenCV) {

}

+(NSImage*)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat;
-(id)initWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat;

@property(nonatomic, readonly) cv::Mat CVMat;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) cv::Mat CVGrayscaleMat;

@end
```

*NSImage+OpenCV.mm:*

```
//
//  NSImage+OpenCV.mm
//

#import "NSImage+OpenCV.h"

static void ProviderReleaseDataNOP(void *info, const void *data, size_t size)
{
    return;
}


@implementation NSImage (NSImage_OpenCV)

-(CGImageRef)CGImage
{
    CGContextRef bitmapCtx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL/*data - pass NULL to let CG allocate the memory*/, 
                                                   [self size].width,  
                                                   [self size].height, 
                                                   8 /*bitsPerComponent*/, 
                                                   0 /*bytesPerRow - CG will calculate it for you if it's allocating the data.  This might get padded out a bit for better alignment*/, 
                                                   [[NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace] CGColorSpace], 
                                                   kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host|kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:bitmapCtx flipped:NO]];
    [self drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0, [self size].width, [self size].height) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapCtx);
    CGContextRelease(bitmapCtx);

    return cgImage;
}


-(cv::Mat)CVMat
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImage];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);
    CGFloat cols = self.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = self.size.height;
    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to backing data
                                                    cols,                      // Width of bitmap
                                                    rows,                     // Height of bitmap
                                                    8,                          // Bits per component
                                                    cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return cvMat;
}

-(cv::Mat)CVGrayscaleMat
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImage];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGFloat cols = self.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = self.size.height;
    cv::Mat cvMat = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1); // 8 bits per component, 1 channel
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to backing data
                                                    cols,                      // Width of bitmap
                                                    rows,                     // Height of bitmap
                                                    8,                          // Bits per component
                                                    cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNone |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return cvMat;
}

+ (NSImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    return [[[NSImage alloc] initWithCVMat:cvMat] autorelease];
}

- (id)initWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1)
    {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    }
    else
    {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                     // Width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                     // Height
                                        8,                                              // Bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                           // Bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                                  // Bytes per row
                                        colorSpace,                                     // Colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,  // Bitmap info flags
                                        provider,                                       // CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                           // Decode
                                        false,                                          // Should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);                     // Intent   


    NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] init];
    [image addRepresentation:bitmapRep];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return image;
}

@end
```

*Example usage:*

Just import it like this:

```
#import "NSImage+OpenCV.h"
```

And use it like this:

```
cv::Mat cvMat_test;
NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
cvMat_test = [image CVMat];
[myImageView setImage:[NSImage imageWithCVMat:cvMat_test]];
```

Comment: there are some memory leaks. [self CGImage] needs to be released, set it to a variable and release after CGContextDrawImage in CVmat and CVGrayscaleMat.
CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImage]; 
...
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

Comment: Changed two more things, you had an extra return and another [self CGImage] call in the draw method causing a leak.

Comment: I did something similar to this to use the data from the bitmapContext. An important gotcha: if you want to use the data from the context, you need to call flushGraphics on the NSGraphicsContext. Without this it worked fine in debug mode but segfaulted in release mode.

Comment: I think that you should also convert OpenCV's BGR representation into RGB before calling the function:

`cv::cvtColor(cvMatBGR_orig, cvMatRGB, CV_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: @dom, why there is `ProviderReleaseDataNOP` function? Is it some trick or you just forgot to remove?

Comment: @VladE.Borovtsov This is just a leftover … Will remove it!

Answer (score 1):

In -(id)initWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat, shouldn't you be adding the representation to self, rather than a new NSImage?

```
-(id)initWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat *)iMat
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        NSData *tData = [NSData dataWithBytes:iMat->data length:iMat->elemSize() * iMat->total()];

        CGColorSpaceRef tColorSpace;

        if(iMat->elemSize() == 1) {
            tColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
        } else {
            tColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        }

        CGDataProviderRef tProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef) tData);

        CGImageRef tImage = CGImageCreate(
            iMat->cols,
            iMat->rows,
            8,
            8 * iMat->elemSize(),
            iMat->step[0],
            tColorSpace,
            kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
            tProvider,
            NULL,
            false,
            kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

        NSBitmapImageRep *tBitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:tImage];
        [self addRepresentation:tBitmap];
        [tBitmap release];

        CGImageRelease(tImage);
        CGDataProviderRelease(tProvider);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(tColorSpace);
    }
    return self;
}
```