# Warnings in Mac OS with Objective-C when running OpenCV

Tags: objective-c, opencv

I am trying to run opencv. I need to display an image in opencv. It is working fine.
I do get the following warning. I need to know what is the meaning of that :

> Warning: Unable to read symbols for @executable_path/../Frameworks/OpenCV.framework/Versions/A/OpenCV (file not found).
>   Warning: Unable to read symbols from "OpenCV" (not yet mapped into memory).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, so I assume you're using the latest OS X and Xcode?

`OpenCV.framework` looks like you're using a precompiled version of OpenCV which is pretty old … The best thing to work with OpenCV on OS X Lion is to compile it yourself … Use this [**guide**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552839/compile-opencv-2-3-1-for-os-x-lion-10-7-2-with-xcode/8559953#8559953).

If you have OpenCV up and running you may need this [**helper**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563356/nsimage-to-cvmat-and-vice-versa/8566020#8566020) to convert your NSImage to an CVMat and vice versa.